# Table design options for large number of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application that sends data based on user interaction (not user input). The data sent could be an Integer, String, Date, or Boolean value. There are 140 keys. We may get anywhere from 1 key value pair to all 140 at a time.

We want to store everything but will only be using 20 out of 140 keys within the application. The remaining will be used for an audit trail later on - so we still need to store them.

This data is used by the application to decide where the user needs to go so it needs to access the record by student id and pull the 20 or so options within  milliseconds. There could be billions of rows of data (it is an upgrade to an existing application with over 20,000 users) so performance is critical. The user generates a new row each time they access the application.

**EXAMPLE DATA:**

```
Score:1
ID:3212
IsLast:False
Action:Completed
```

I have 2 ideas on how to do this and looking for some help on which is best or is a third option a better choice.

**OPTION 1:**

My first idea is to use a column for the value as a string then have a look-up table of possible data types to use when the value needs to be Cast for use.

```
value       | dataType
-----------------------
"1"         | int
"Completed" | string
```

While the data being sent is not user generated I know there must be a gotcha somewhere in this method. The only reason for doing this is that we don't know what key:pair will be sent (outside of date and id) and trying to avoid more than a few columns.

The SO Question
[How to Handle Unknown Data Type in one Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227456/how-to-handle-unknown-data-type-in-one-table) uses a similar idea.

**OPTION 2:**

The other solution is to have 140 columns - one for each key. However, the amount of data generated is very large (billions of rows) so that calling this data will not be fast enough - I don't think.

**Technical Details:**
This is using SQL Server 2008 - not R2 with DotNet C# and Reporting Services.

Am I missing something here - what is the best way to create this table for performance?

Comment: Third option: Get the data as XML, store in an NVARCHAR(max) data type.

Comment: Will this not slow down Reporting Services when a report is generated.

Comment: i would put it in an XML

Comment: Key value tables are horrible for performance, I would never consider them in a relational database where performance was a key component. Listen to Charles Bretana, he has the best design choice.

Comment: Do not put it in XML. This will slow down access and make retrieving the data more complex. Take full advantage of the data structure that the database already is providing. Go with Option 1 for a good balance of speed, extensibility, and readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vertically segment your data.  Put the 20 keys that are necessary for navigational control in one table, all 20 in one row, with PK that identifies the user Interaction (Callit say, `InteractionId`).    Put the other 120 values in another table, with composite Primary Key, based on the PK of the first table (`InteractionId`, plus the `KeyTypeId` identifying which of the 120 possible key value pairs the value is for.  Store all the values in this second table as strings.  In a third lookup table called, say, `KeyTypes`, store the `KeyTypeId`, `KeyTypeName`, and `KeyValueDataType` to allow your code to know how to cast the string value to output it properly as either a string, datetime, an integer, or a decimal value or whatever...

The first table will be accessed much more often, and so it contains only those values which the application's navigational functionality needs more frequent access to, keeping the rows narrower, which allows more rows per page, and minimizes disk IO.  Putting all 20 values in one row will keep the row count smaller (~ 1/20th as large), minimizng the depth of the index seeks that will need to be performed for each access.

The other table with all the other 120 key-values will not be accessed as frequently, so it's structure can probably be optimized for logical simplicity rather than for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you might merge the suggestions offered so far:

Create a table with the 20 keys necessary for navigational control, plus one column for a Primary Key, plus one column that is an XML data type to store the rest of the possible data. You could then create a DTD that handles the data types for each key, plus constraints on certain keys as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well it should be simple enough to test both ideas, but a variation on option 1 looks favoured to me. RDBMSs like SQL Server prefer long, narrow tables (i.e. fewer columns but lots of rows).

I won't go any further because it appears Charles has beat to it, with a perfectly sensible suggestion.